# onsubmit method vs submit event listener

Tags: javascript, dom-events

I have been doing a mail program for a course, and I am encountering behaviour I do not understand related to preventing form submission via return false:

Case 1: Form submission is not properly prevented and DOM is reloaded giving a 200 error

```
document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', () => {

send_email();

load_mailbox('inbox');

return false;

})
```

Case 2: Form submission is properly prevented and DOM is not reloaded returning an expected 201 code

```
document.querySelector('#compose-form').onsubmit = () => {

send_email();

load_mailbox('inbox');

return false;

}
```

Comment: Use `event.preventDefault` when using addEventListener

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The difference is that `onsubmit` replaces the current (already assigned) function. `addEventListener` on the other hand adds an additional command to the already existent property.

So in your case when using `addEventListener` you need to prevent the default behavior with a `preventDefault` function.

Try this:

```js
// add event as an argument
document.querySelector('#compose-form').addEventListener('submit', (event) => {
  event.preventDefault(); // add this line

  // and then do your stuff
  send_email();
  load_mailbox('inbox');
  return false;

})
```

Comment: So in this case the already assigned function would be the form submission?

Comment: @AAM exactly 

Comment: The problem with this solution is the if the `send_email()` function takes a while, and the `load_mailbox()` runs in the meantime, you will not have all the latest information. How do you solve this?