# Why I can't fetch the json response of django using javascript fetch API?

Tags: javascript, html, django, django-views, django-templates

I am new to JavaScript. I'm working on a project in which I'm using Django in the backend. My Django views function will produce a JSON response which my javascript fetch will get it. Here is my Django views function that produces a JSON response. My motive is to make a like button that will update the like button's appearance and the number of likes by clicking on that button without reloading the whole page. This is the last requirement of my project. I am trying for a long time, a couple of days.

```
def likepost(request,posts_id):
  posts = NewPost.objects.get(id = posts_id)
  is_like = False
  for like in posts.likepost.all():
    if like == request.user and request.method == "POST":
        is_like = True
        break

  if not is_like:
     posts.likepost.add(request.user)

  else:
    posts.likepost.remove(request.user)
  posts.save()
  # serialize_obj = serializers.serialize("json",posts_id)

  return JsonResponse({
    "is_like" : is_like,
    "num_like" : posts.likepost.count()
   },safe=False)
```

My javascript will make an API of the JSON data generated the above views function using fetch. Here is my javascript full code.

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded",function(e){
    // const colon = document.createElement('div');
    // colon.setAttribute('id','colon')
    e.preventDefault()
    // const likebtn = document.createElement('button');
    // likebtn.setAttribute('class','likebtn btn btn-primary');
    // likebtn.setAttribute('class','likebtn');
    // document.querySelector('.card-footer').appendChild(likebtn);
    // document.querySelector('.likebtn').innerHTML = "Like";
    document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).onsubmit = like_function();
    // document.querySelector('.likepost').addEventListener('click', ()=> like_function('likepost'));
})



// let is_like = "{{is_like}}";
// let num_like = "{{num_like}}";

function like_function(){
    // document.createElement('button').innerHTML = "Love";
    fetch(`/like/${posts_id}`)
    // ,{
    //     method:"POST",
    //     body : JSON.stringify({
    //         "is_like" : is_like,
    //         "num_like" : num_like,
    //     })
    // })
    .then(response => response.json())
    .then(result => {
        if(result.is_like){
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Unike";
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
        else{
            document.querySelector(`#likebtn${posts_id}`).innerHTML = "Like";
            // location.replace("http://127.0.0.1:8000")
        }
    })
    
}

// function like_function(){
//     if (document.querySelector("#like").style.color == "blue"){
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "red";
//     }else{
//         document.querySelector("#like").style.color = "blue";
//     }
// }
```

Here is my urls.py file.

```
urlpatterns = [
   path("", views.index, name="index"),
   path("login", views.login_view, name="login"),
   path("logout", views.logout_view, name="logout"),
   path("register", views.register, name="register"),
   path("profile/<int:id>",views.profilepage,name="profile"),


    
    path("profile/<int:id>/following/addfollower",views.followersPeople,name="addfollower"),
   path("profile/<int:id>/following/removefollower",views.followersRemove,name="removefollower),
    path("postform", views.createpost, name="postform"),
    path("editform/<int:id>",views.editpost,name="editpost"),
    path("following",views.followerspost,name="following"),
    path("like/<int:posts_id>",views.likepost, name="likepost"),
    path("postpage/<int:id>",views.view_post,name="postpage"),
]+ static(settings.MEDIA_URL, document_root= settings.MEDIA_ROOT)
```

I am also sharing my template here.

```html
{% load static %}
<div class="card-footer">
   
    <form action="{% url 'likepost' posts_id=posts.id %}" class="likeform" method="POST" style="display: inline;">
        {% csrf_token %}
        <button id="likebtn{{posts.id}}" class="btn btn-link" type="submit">Like</button>
    </form>
    <small class="num_of_likes">{{ posts.likepost.all.count }}</small>
    
    {% block script %} 
        <script>
            let posts_id = "{{ posts.id }}";
        </script>
        <script src="{% static 'network/controller.js' %}"></script>
    {% endblock %}
    <button class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Comment</button>
    <a href="{% url 'postpage' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">View Post</a>
    {% if request.user.id is posts.user.id %}
        <a href="{% url 'editpost' id=posts.id %}" class="btn btn-link" style="text-decoration: none;">Edit</a>
       
    {% endif %}
    <div class="likepost"></div>
</div>
```

My project doesn't work well. When I click on the like button it appears like [this](https://youtu.be/pH8G2LU8S-c)

instead of updating the like button into the unlike button and the number of likes as well as the page shouldn't be reloaded. What should I do? Please let me know if I need to share more pieces of code although I see my code is very much messier.

Answer (score 0):

In your video it looks like the form is being sent instead of preventing the POST default.

```js
    document.querySelector(`.likeform`).onsubmit = () => like_function();
```

[Look into this answer for more detail about `.onsubmit`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/66612034/onsubmit-method-vs-submit-event-listener#:%7E:text=1%20Answer&text=The%20difference%20is%20that%20onsubmit,behavior%20with%20a%20preventDefault%20function.)